# @Observes in sessionscoped bean?

Tags: events, java-ee-6, observer-pattern, cdi

is following scenario possible?

"SessionService" which is a stateless EJB fires an event "LoggedInEvent". A SessionScoped (Weld) bean "SessionBean" having a non static method observing the LoggedInEvent is called and initializes some things for that specific user.

Is the correct instance of "SessionBean" called? Are all instances called? I can not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The correct instance" is a slightly misleading wording.

What happens is this:

1. The `SessionService` is invoked (probably triggered by a web request).
2. If it fires its `LoggedInEvent`, all registered observers are called in a synchronous way (meaning that `SessionService` will not terminate before all observers terminate).
3. Each bean containing a (non-static) observer method will be instantiated (provided that the bean scope is active - which it usually is in a standard web environment(*)). This will be the case for your `SessionBean`. If - and only if - `SessionBean` has already been instantiated *in your active session* (there's certainly only one session active regarding the web request), then this instance will of course be used.

More details in the [spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/injectionelresolution.html#observers).

So, to answer you question:

Yes, the correct instance will be called. Why? Because it's the responsibility of the container to make sure that only one `SessionBean`-instance is associated with the active session scope.

(*): If an invocation is for example triggered by a remote ejb call, you can neither  assume an active session nor an active conversation...