# CDI Event fired, but not received by all threads/sessions

Tags: java, cdi

I have a simple setup with just one single Session that backs a JSF xhtml file. Within that I fire an event, expeting that both the same session, and any other session will receive the event on submitting.

However, oddly enough, I can see that during the firing of the event, only the current session receives it, not any other sessions. I am making sure I have two different sessions by using two different browsers (Safari and Firefox in this case).

Do I have the concept of CDI based Events wrong?

The bean backing the session:

```java
package testevent;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.event.Reception;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestEventSession implements Serializable {
  private String message = "Start Message";
  private String receivedMessage = "";
  
  @Inject
  @ForTest Event<String> messageEvent;
  
  Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
  
  public void messageChanged(@Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS) @ForTest String message) {
    LOG.info("messageChanged <-- "+message);
    this.receivedMessage = message;
  }

  public String getReceivedMessage() {
    return receivedMessage;
  }
  
  public String getMessage() {
    LOG.info("getMessage --> "+message);
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    LOG.info("setMessage <-- "+message);
    this.message = message;
    LOG.info("Firing Message Change");
    messageEvent.fire(message);
    LOG.info("Done Firing Message Change");
  }
}
```

The xhtml file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  >
  <f:view transient="false">
    <h:body>
      <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{testEventSession.message}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{testEventSession.receivedMessage}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        <h:button value="Refresh" />
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

The Qualifier used is a very basic one:

```
package testevent;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface ForTest {
}
```

As part of the debugging output, you can see that only the observer method in the current thread/session receives the event:

```
10:45:11.213 [GUEST] [http-nio-8080-exec-32] INFO  testevent.TestEventSession - Firing Message Change
10:45:11.213 [GUEST] [http-nio-8080-exec-32] INFO  testevent.TestEventSession - messageChanged <-- Start Message #3
10:45:11.213 [GUEST] [http-nio-8080-exec-32] INFO  testevent.TestEventSession - Done Firing Message Change
```

Note that this has been tested with TomEE 7.0.3, which uses assumingely OpenWebBeans 1.7.3.

## Related

- [@Observes in sessionscoped bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524170/observes-in-sessionscoped-bean)
- [CDI Events, scope of their propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835516/cdi-events-scope-of-their-propagation)
- [Do CDI Events observed across session scoped JSF backing beans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481921/744133)
- [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#_event_example)

## Update

It might be that this is an intended feature, however I could not find this explicitly stated in the CDI-Spec. Although the provided example seems to be making sense only when the `Observer` only Observes fired events within the same session. In the case of `Produces` it clearly states the inter-workings with scoped beans. I think it is rather some documentation lagging in the official spec.

So far other solutions seem to be:

- Manually registering and tracking session beans
- Use of JMS / Message Driven Beans (MDB).

Comment: This issue is similar to this, where event is fired from `ApplicationScoped` to `SessionScoped` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481921/744133. Mine is only different as it fires from `SessionScoped` to `SessionScoped`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notify all @SessionScoped-Beans-Instances from all Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530724/notify-all-sessionscoped-beans-instances-from-all-users)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On observer side only currently active session will catch it by spec. If you want to broadcast on all sessions you need to keep track of them in a registry.

5.5.6 of CDI 2.0:

> Obtain a contextual instance of the bean which declares the observer method according to Contextual instance of a bean.

The contextual instance is defined in 6.5.3 as

> the instance served by the context of the current scope.

Comment: Yep, very concretely a beam instance is a single in a context from the spec words and a session is identified from the current active request. Mix both statements and you have the behavior you observe.

Comment: If you find the part of the spec that clarifies that, I will accept the answer (I couldn’t find it).

Comment: 5.5.6 of CDI 2.0: "Obtain a contextual instance of the bean which declares the observer method according to
Contextual instance of a bean.", the contextual instance is defined in  6.5.3 as the instance served by the context of the current scope.